# ngFor on a list without creating an intermediate variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, loops, ngfor

Is there a way to make an *ngFor without creating an intermediate variable : 
In the example below I declare item but I don't use it, is there a way to remove it?

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
   <span>{{items[i]}}</span>
   <span>{{items[i+1]}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: technically you cant remove it but instead what you can do is <span>{{item}}</span> as *ngFor="let <value> of <collection>" is syntax of angular.

Comment: Why you don't use it?

<span>{{item}}</span>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `ngFor` [template syntax](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#syntax), without the `let-item` part:

```
<ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="items" let-i="index">
  <div>
    <span>{{items[i]}}</span>
    <span>{{items[i+1]}}</span>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

See [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9aaicp) for a demo.

For more explanations about `ngFor`, `*ngFor` and `ng-template`, see [this article](https://toddmotto.com/angular-ngfor-template-element#ngfor-and-ng-template) by Todd Motto.